# Jxplorer certificate for ldap

Tags: ldap, certificate, openldap, tivoli

I don't know if someone is familiar with Tivoli Directory Server (ldap) but I guess there is something more or less the same in every ldap software.

So, there is a setting for ssl authentication which can be serverClientAuth and serverAuth. With serverAuth it is sufficient for the server to provide the certificate and the client (jxplorer) just accepts it to connect. With serverClientAuth except from the certificate provided by the server also the client needs to have its certificate on the server.

In my setup I have the serverClientAuth setting. So I was wondering if it is possible for jxplorer to provide the client certificate to the ldap server.

Any thoughts are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, and there is a menu provided specifically for that purpose, which lets you define they KeyStore, truststore, and various other SSL things.

Comment: Can you provide more info?